# Write data in text file

Tags: javascript

I have used below code:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var s = fso.CreateTextFile("test.txt", true);
    for(var j=1;j<9;j++)
    {
        s.WriteLine('Test'  + j);
    }
    s.Close();
```

Getting below error when I run above code: 
**ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined**

Comment: What are you using to run this code?

Comment: Supported in the following document modes: Quirks, Internet Explorer 6 standards, Internet Explorer 7 standards, Internet Explorer 8 standards, Internet Explorer 9 standards, Internet Explorer 10 standards, Internet Explorer 11 standards. In other words, modern browsers don't support ActiveXObjects anymore.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: You could try toying with data:url's or just use a serverside script to create the file and offer it for download. Certain versions of IE also support: `window.navigator.msSaveBlob()` which can be used to generate text files.

Comment: I have used Chrome and Mozila browser

Comment: I have used HTML file to run this code

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveXObject` is available only on IE browser. So every other useragent will throw an error

On other browsers,
you could any of this:

- [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications) or
- [File writer API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/) (this is currently implemented [Chrome browser only](http://caniuse.com/filesystem))

Comment: Moreover, even with Internet Explorer, this will not work unless you [*severely* reduce the security options](https://forums.asp.net/t/1295469.aspx?unable+to+create+ActiveXObject+Scripting+FileSystemObject+object+).

Comment: @Captain Jack: Code not working on IE browser. Also I have read documentation on File API but in this documentation there is no code to write file.

Comment: What is the issue that you are having now?

Answer (score 0):

try this 
This will work only on IE8

```
 <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
 function WriteToFile(passForm) {

    set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");  
    set s = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\test.txt", True);
    s.writeline("HI");
    s.writeline("Bye");
    s.writeline("-----------------------------");
    s.Close();
 }
  </SCRIPT>

</head>

<body>
<p>To sign up for the Excel workshop please fill out the form below:
</p>
<form onSubmit="WriteToFile(this)">
Type your first name:
<input type="text" name="FirstName" size="20">
<br>Type your last name:
<input type="text" name="LastName" size="20">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

cridte @667776 @Faraona [Faraona](https://stackoverflow.com/users/667776/faraona)

Comment: This will work in IE8 or earlier only (createObject is not supported since IE9).